# problem with 3 button layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity with three buttons in the layout. All the buttons are at the bottom. I wanted the button to be extreme left,centre and extreme right. The extreme right and the extreme left buttons are fine. However, the centre button is taking up all the space in between the left and right button. However, I want the middle button to take necessary space and not all the space. Also, I am unable to move the imageButton to the middle of the screen. Any help with these things? Here's my XML layout file:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/backgroundnr"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            >

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tempText2"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tempText"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/start"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            >
            </ImageButton>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tempText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Touch to Start"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            >
            </TextView>

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100px"
            android:src="@drawable/bottombar"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >
            </ImageView>

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/profileButtons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Profile"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/profiledefault"
            android:gravity = "bottom"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bottomlayout"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            >
            </Button>
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/savedButtons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Saved"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/favoritesdefault"
            android:gravity = "bottom"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileButtons"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/recentButtons"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            >
            </Button>
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/recentButtons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Recent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/recentdefault"
            android:gravity = "bottom"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            >
            </Button>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: take a look to the layout_weight property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

for your ImageButton instead of layout_gravity.

and to rearrange your bottom buttons.

don't use leftOf or rightOf for middle button which is "savedButtons" . just use

`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

for it. And for the left button "profileButtons" use

```
android:layout_toLeftOf = "@+id/savedButtons"
```

for the right button "recentButtons" use

```
android:layout_toRightOf = "@+id/savedButtons"
```

In this layout middle button will occupy the center space necessary , and the remaining left and right areas are used for the remaining buttons. you will need `alignParentBottom` for each of 3 buttons.

HTH.

Comment: thanks. totally worked. just didnt need the part commented out.